# I need help finding ground for a STM32F446RET6-LQFP64 microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, ground, vcc

I am making my own detailed PCB for my school project. I chose the STM32F446RET6-LQFP64 microcontroller for it, but I can't find its ground pin.  Can anyone give me detailed information about this microcontroller?

Comment: search for the word "ground" in the datasheet

Answer (score 1):

In datasheets on STM MCU's GND pins called VSS, GNDA (analog GND) called VSSA. You can check it in datasheet section where capacitor consideration takes place.